# Double curly braces error with ReactDOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What's causing this error?

```
Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected ,
{ Object.keys(form_routes).map( (key,index) => <Route path={key} component={{ form_routes[key] }}></Route> ) }
```

at `{{ form_routes[key] }}`

full relevant code:

```
const form_routes = {
    'start': "Start",
    'part1': "Part1",
    'part2': "Part2",
    'part3': "Part3",
    'part4': "Part4",
    'part5': "Part5",
    'part6': "Part6"
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={hashHistory} render={applyMiddleware(useRelativeLinks())}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRedirect to='/search'/>
            <Route path='main' component={MainMenu}/>
            <Route path='search' component={Search}/>
            <Route path='form' component={Form}>
                <IndexRedirect to='start'/>
                { Object.keys(form_routes).map( (key,index) => <Route path={key} component={{ form_routes[key] }}></Route> ) }
            </Route>
        </Route>
      </Router>
    </Provider>,
    root
);
```

Works if plain:

```
<Route path='start' component={Start}></Route>
<Route path='part1' component={Part1}></Route>
<Route path='part2' component={Part2}></Route>
<Route path='part3' component={Part3}></Route>
<Route path='part4' component={Part4}></Route>
<Route path='part5' component={Part5}></Route>
<Route path='part6' component={Part6}></Route>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`component={...}` is supposed to contain an expression. The expression you're giving it is `{ form_routes[key] }`, which is an invalid object initializer. This would trigger the same error:

```
console.log({ form_routes[key] });
```

You probably just wanted `component={ form_routes[key] }`.

Comment: when it's just `component={ form_routes[key] }` it doesn't display my components. I think it's because it's equal to `component="Start"`. Which doesn't work as the other Routes pattern are `component={Start}`

Comment: @A.Lau: Of course it doesn't, `form_routes` contains strings. `{"Start"}` != `{Start}`. You'd have to put an equivalent value in `form_routes` (`Start`, not `"Start"`), and then `{ form_routes[key] }` would work.

Comment: Thanks. That was kinda stupid of me. The curly braces confused me for a bit.